# is it possible store PDF or HTML content in snowflake.Please help us what is the best data type to store PDF or HTML data. How to retrieve that

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, custom-data-type

is it possible store PDF or HTML content in snowflake.Please help us what is the best data type to store PDF or HTML data. How to retrieve that

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you planning to do with this data?

Comment: databases really should not be used as arbitrary file systems. Ether you care about the data and you want to filter on some property of it, or you need to manipulate the data. But if you are just want to fetch the 10 documents that are from X, can turn around in your code and retrieve those same N documents by URI from an cloud storage. Yes more code, but file sizes are not problems, and you are paying for the storage of the raw files, not to have them sit in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store HTML or PDF for any technical reason, you can use binary date type which can store such files up to 8Mb size. However, you could not query binary date type directly in your query.

If you have to extract any information, you can use python CLI and use python libraries to extract additional information, but you can not use SQL to extract any information.

HTML can be saved as XML but you can try that as it has couple of limitation and not sure if XML parsing is available in GA or still preview.

Comment: Thank you.as there is size limit to use binary data type.is there any other way to store the pdf like  load that into S3 bucket and refer the URL.but not sure how can we do that.if there is any practice lab link, kindly provide

Comment: Yes, you can store them in S3 lake and keep a link to the snowflake table, however, I am not sure if that will serve your purpose or not. I am not sure what is your use case and what you would do with PDF and how you want to consume the PDF, it all depends on that.

Comment: Thank you. After discussing with the team we are planning to store it in binary data type.Can you help me how can we store the HTML content file in Binary data type.

Comment: Well, as I told you, all semi-structured data can stored as variant including xml but only thing that if all the HTML having same structure so you can run an SQL or they are just html doc (like blog content) in such case xml may not help and better store in binary format.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has new unstructured data storage and querying functionality now. You can store the PDF in a stage and use a directory table to view the file list within the stage.  You can create scoped URL's, etc. to allow applications to render the PDF files, etc.